# Magento cannot rebuild cache

Tags: magento, caching, shopping-cart

RESOLVED: Thanks to some ongoing help from fkim and Slayer Birden, I was able to narrow my problem down to the checkout.xml file.  After lots of goofy trial and error, I just compared my file to the magento original and started removing my changes.  A change I made in which I had commented out line 318 was the culprit.  Thanks all.

(old thread follows)
EDIT: So I just tried refreshing individual caches and checking the site. Refreshing the "Configuration" cache did not cause trouble, but the "Layout" cache seems to be the culprit.  Does this change things?

ORIGINAL:
So I have a Magento site at cart.oldfloridian.com that breaks up a bit when I try to refresh caches.

Everything will be working fine and then when I refresh caches, the shopping cart sidebar widget disappears and the checkout/cart and checkout/onepage pages stop loading content if you navigate to them directly.  That is, they load header, sidebar, footer, but no page-specific content.

Then I can restore the site to an earlier backup and everything is back and running.  Refresh caches. No shopping cart again.  Currently I've restored and so the cart is present.

So where do I start?  I am a designer mostly so this permissions/caching stuff is a bit opaque to me.

var/cache is set to 755, as are its subdirectories.  Their files are 600s and 644s.  Is this a problem?

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

EDIT: So checkout.xml is below.  I'm not sure what I am looking for, but things seem alright.  The one change I made was to comment out that line showing user login, in order to make the entire site "guest only."  Anyone else see anything?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */

-->
<layout version="0.1.0">

<!--
Default layout, loads most of the pages
-->

    <default>

        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <reference name="top.links">
            <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
                <action method="addCartLink"></action>
                <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>

    <checkout_cart_index translate="label">
        <label>Shopping Cart</label>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">
                <action method="setCartTemplate"><value>checkout/cart.phtml</value></action>
                <action method="setEmptyTemplate"><value>checkout/cart/noItems.phtml</value></action>
                <action method="chooseTemplate"/>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>

                <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.top_methods" as="top_methods" translate="label">
                    <label>Payment Methods Before Checkout Button</label>
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml"/>
                </block>

                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="checkout.cart.form.before" as="form_before" translate="label">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Form Before</label>
                </block>

                <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.methods" as="methods" translate="label">
                    <label>Payment Methods After Checkout Button</label>
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml"/>
                    <block type="checkout/multishipping_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.multishipping" template="checkout/multishipping/link.phtml"/>
                </block>

                <!--<block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>
                <block type="checkout/cart_shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="checkout/cart/shipping.phtml"/> -->
                <block type="checkout/cart_crosssell" name="checkout.cart.crosssell" as="crosssell" template="checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml"/>

                <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.cart.totals" as="totals" template="checkout/cart/totals.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" translate="label">
            <label>Additional Product Info</label>
        </block>
    </checkout_cart_index>

    <checkout_cart_configure translate="label">
        <label>Configure Cart Item</label>
        <update handle="catalog_product_view"/>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="checkout/cart_item_configure" name="checkout.cart.item.configure.block"></block>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_configure>

<!--
Multi address shipping checkout main layout,
will be rendered on all checkout pages
-->

    <checkout_multishipping translate="label">
        <label>Multishipping Checkout</label>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/multishipping_state" name="checkout_state" template="checkout/multishipping/state.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </checkout_multishipping>

    <checkout_multishipping_login>
        <update handle="customer_account_login"/>
    </checkout_multishipping_login>

    <checkout_multishipping_register>
        <update handle="customer_account_create"/>
    </checkout_multishipping_register>

<!--
Multi address shipping checkout selection of address per item page
-->

    <checkout_multishipping_address_select translate="label">
        <label>Multishipping Checkout Shipping Address Selection</label>
        <update handle="checkout_multishipping"/>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/multishipping_address_select" name="checkout_address_select" template="checkout/multishipping/address/select.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </checkout_multishipping_address_select>

    <checkout_multishipping_address_selectbilling translate="label">
        <label>Multishipping Checkout Billing Address Selection</label>
        <update handle="checkout_multishipping"/>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/multishipping_address_select" name="checkout_address_select" template="checkout/multishipping/address/select.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </checkout_multishipping_address_selectbilling>


    <checkout_multishipping_address_newshipping translate="label">
        <label>Multishipping Checkout Shipping Address Creation</label>
        <update handle="checkout_multishipping"/>
        <update handle="checkout_multishipping_customer_address"/>
    </checkout_multishipping_address_newshipping>

    <checkout_multishipping_address_newbilling translate="label">
        <label>Multishipping Checkout Billing Address Creation</label>
        <update handle="checkout_multishipping"/>
        <update handle="checkout_multishipping_customer_address"/>
    </checkout_multishipping_address_newbilling>

    <checkout_multishipping_address_editshipping translate="label">
        <label>Multishipping Checkout Shipping Address Edit Form</label>
        <update handle="checkout_multishipping"/>
        <update handle="checkout_multishipping_customer_address"/>
    </checkout_multishipping_address_editshipping>

    <checkout_multishipping_address_editaddress>
        <update handle="checkout_multishipping"/>
        <update handle="checkout_multishipping_customer_address"/>
    </checkout_multishipping_address_editaddress>

    <checkout_multishipping_address_editbilling translate="label">
        <label>Multishipping Checkout Billing Address Edit Form</label>
        <update handle="checkout_multishipping"/>
        <update handle="checkout_multishipping_customer_address"/>
    </checkout_multishipping_address_editbilling>

    <checkout_multishipping_customer_address translate="label">
        <label>Multishipping Checkout Customer Address Edit Form</label>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="customer/address_edit" name="customer_address_edit" template="customer/address/edit.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </checkout_multishipping_customer_address>

<!--
Multi address shipping checkout address page
-->

    <checkout_multishipping_addresses translate="label">
        <label>Multishipping Checkout Address (Any) Form</label>
        <update handle="checkout_multishipping"/>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/multishipping_addresses" name="checkout_addresses" template="checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/multishipping/item/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/multishipping/item/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/multishipping/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </checkout_multishipping_addresses>

<!--
Multi address shipping checkout shipping information
-->

    <checkout_multishipping_shipping translate="label">
        <label>Multishipping Checkout Shipping Information Step</label>
        <update handle="checkout_multishipping"/>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/multishipping_shipping" name="checkout_shipping" template="checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/multishipping/item/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/multishipping/item/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/multishipping/item/default.phtml</template></action>

                <block type="checkout/multishipping_billing_items" name="checkout_billing_items" template="checkout/multishipping/billing/items.phtml">
                    <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/multishipping/item/default.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/multishipping/item/default.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/multishipping/item/default.phtml</template></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </checkout_multishipping_shipping>

<!--
Multi address shipping checkout billing information
-->

    <checkout_multishipping_billing translate="label">
        <label>Multishipping Checkout Billing Information Step</label>
        <update handle="checkout_multishipping"/>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/multishipping_billing" name="checkout_billing" template="checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml">
                <action method="setMethodFormTemplate"><method>purchaseorder</method><template>payment/form/purchaseorder.phtml</template></action>

                <!--<block type="checkout/multishipping_billing_items" name="checkout_billing_items" template="checkout/multishipping/billing/items.phtml">
                    <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/multishipping/item/default.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/multishipping/item/default.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/multishipping/item/default.phtml</template></action>
                </block>-->

            </block>
        </reference>
    </checkout_multishipping_billing>

<!--
Multi address shipping checkout overview
-->

    <checkout_multishipping_overview translate="label">
        <label>Multishipping Checkout Overview</label>
        <update handle="checkout_multishipping"/>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/multishipping_overview" name="checkout_overview" template="checkout/multishipping/overview.phtml">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/multishipping/item/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/multishipping/item/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/multishipping/item/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addRowItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/multishipping/overview/item.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addRowItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/multishipping/overview/item.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="checkout/multishipping_payment_info" name="payment_info">
                    <action method="setInfoTemplate"><method></method><template></template></action>
                </block>
                <block type="checkout/agreements" name="checkout.multishipping.agreements" as="agreements" template="checkout/multishipping/agreements.phtml"/>
                <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="totals" />
                <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.multishipping.overview.items.after" as="items_after" translate="label">
                    <label>Overview Items After</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </checkout_multishipping_overview>

<!--
Multi address shipping checkout success
-->

    <checkout_multishipping_success translate="label">
        <label>Multishipping Checkout Success</label>
        <update handle="checkout_multishipping"/>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/multishipping_success" name="checkout_success" template="checkout/multishipping/success.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </checkout_multishipping_success>

<!--
One page checkout main layout
-->

    <checkout_onepage_index translate="label">
        <label>One Page Checkout</label>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="right">
            <action method="unsetChildren"></action>
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="checkout.progress.wrapper" translate="label">
                <label>Checkout Progress Wrapper</label>
                <action method="setElementId"><value>checkout-progress-wrapper</value></action>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="checkout.progress" before="-" template="checkout/onepage/progress.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/onepage" name="checkout.onepage" template="checkout/onepage.phtml">
                <!--block type="checkout/onepage_login" name="checkout.onepage.login" as="login" template="checkout/onepage/login.phtml"-->
                    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="checkout.onepage.login.before" as="login_before" translate="label">
                        <label>Login/Registration Before</label>
                        <action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action>
                    </block>
                </block>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_billing" name="checkout.onepage.billing" as="billing" template="checkout/onepage/billing.phtml"/>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping" name="checkout.onepage.shipping" as="shipping" template="checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml"/>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method" name="checkout.onepage.shipping_method" as="shipping_method" template="checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml">
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method_available" name="checkout.onepage.shipping_method.available" as="available" template="checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml"/>
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method_additional" name="checkout.onepage.shipping_method.additional" as="additional" template="checkout/onepage/shipping_method/additional.phtml"/>
                </block>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_payment" name="checkout.onepage.payment" as="payment" template="checkout/onepage/payment.phtml">
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_payment_methods" name="checkout.payment.methods" as="methods" template="checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml">
                        <action method="setMethodFormTemplate"><method>purchaseorder</method><template>payment/form/purchaseorder.phtml</template></action>
                    </block>
                </block>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_review" name="checkout.onepage.review" as="review" template="checkout/onepage/review.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>

<!--
One page checkout progress block
-->

    <checkout_onepage_progress>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/progress.phtml">
            <block type="checkout/onepage_payment_info" name="payment_info">
                <action method="setInfoTemplate"><method></method><template></template></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </checkout_onepage_progress>

<!--
One page checkout payment methods block
-->
    <checkout_onepage_paymentmethod>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <block type="checkout/onepage_payment_methods" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml">
            <action method="setMethodFormTemplate"><method>purchaseorder</method><template>payment/form/purchaseorder.phtml</template></action>
        </block>
    </checkout_onepage_paymentmethod>


<!--
One page checkout shipping methods block
-->

    <checkout_onepage_shippingmethod>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method_available" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml"/>
    </checkout_onepage_shippingmethod>

    <checkout_onepage_additional>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method_additional" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/shipping_method/additional.phtml">
            <action method="setDontDisplayContainer"><param>1</param></action>
        </block>
    </checkout_onepage_additional>

<!--
One page checkout order review block
-->

    <checkout_onepage_review translate="label">
        <label>One Page Checkout Overview</label>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <block type="checkout/onepage_review_info" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.totals" as="totals" template="checkout/onepage/review/totals.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.before" as="items_before" translate="label">
                <label>Items Before</label>
            </block>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.after" as="items_after" translate="label">
                <label>Items After</label>
            </block>
            <block type="checkout/agreements" name="checkout.onepage.agreements" as="agreements" template="checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/template" name="checkout.onepage.review.button" as="button" template="checkout/onepage/review/button.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </checkout_onepage_review>

    <checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
        <label>One Page Checkout Success</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/onepage_success" name="checkout.success" template="checkout/success.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_success>
    <checkout_onepage_failure translate="label">
        <label>One Page Checkout Failure</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/onepage_failure" name="checkout.failure" template="checkout/onepage/failure.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_failure>
    <block type="core/list" name="additional.product.info"/>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first check `/var/log/exception.log` for any errors and delete the /var folder - see if it gets built again. If there's no /var folder after trying to rebuild the cache, it's most likely a permission related issue.

Comment: So I don't have a var/log/exception.log.  I do have a system.log, which seems to have just some unrelated stuff - errors relating to an adaptiveResize mod that I unsuccessfully tried to implement as well as some undefined product fields like brand and ptitle.  I tried renaming /var to see if it would rebuild and it does, though it rebuilt with 777 permissions rather than 755.  Issue?  Also it currently only has a cache folder in it, but perhaps this is because I haven't navigated the site enough to build the other folders?

Comment: Does the cache folder contain any files? What is the size of it? It is possible that your cache is rebuilt.

Comment: /var/cache does appear to have all the original cache files.  Trouble is though that this doesn't bring back the shopping cart.  In the comments to the answer above, I mention that I've since discovered that it is only the "Layout" cache that causes the crash.  Any advice on where to look considering that?

Comment: restore the layout xml file from the original Magento installation (or base/default if you haven't edited it) and do your customisation needed one by one.

Comment: Actually - renaming /var to create a new one does create the new cache, but it also causes the cart to disappear.  Switching the orginial /var back to the proper path returns the cart.  So yes, definitely something wrong with that newly created /var.  Old var has directories also for cache, log, locks, package, report, an htaccess, etc.  New /var only has cache.

Comment: Remember your cart should NEVER be cached.

Comment: Cart should never be cached.  Is there a place I may have set the cart to cache?

Comment: Where is layout.xml?  I don't see that file in base/default/layout.  Or do you mean restore the entire /layout directory?

Comment: I meant restore your checkout.xml - let me know

Comment: Hmm, okay so I restored checkout.xml to the magento original and then refreshed the Layout cache in admin Cache Management.  It still makes the shopping cart disappear, but now if I navigate directly to mydomain/checkout/cart that page loads fine, and it appears that I can continue with the checkout process.  To be honest I haven't been checking this bit a lot recently, but I know that at one point navigating directly to that page would load no content.  So that's an improvement!  Now I just need to get the cart sidebar widget to appear again on the site.

Answer (score 2):

The Magento's merged XML configuration is stored in the cache. I think that is the place where you're having troubles. Most likely your new config is broken for Checkout pages. You'll need to check "checkout.xml" layout file and see if it's valid. Also check your module config in the Checkout module folder.

It wouldn't hurt to look in the logs as well, since some info about the error might be there.

Comment: That or a change was made to a .phtml file and never fully debugged and the cache cleared. Weeks later upon cache clear, the system massively fails as html blocks cache or as noted above, the layout cache gets refreshed.

Comment: Aha, I just tried refreshing individual caches and checking the site. Refreshing the "Configuration" cache did not cause trouble, but the "Layout" cache seems to be the culprit.  Does this change things?

Comment: What am I looking for in the Checkout module config? I've attached that file to the original question if someone would take a look... Fiasco Labs - if your suggestion is the case, any idea how I would go about finding the source?